# English to reginol language in android works but regional language to english not works

Tags: android

```
I am developing an application where 2 languages there English,Hindi.
```

if i change from english to hindi the date picker changed to hindi , but if i change from hindi to english still date picker shows hindi onli instead of English

i am using below

Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);

```
    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though i set the locale whenever i changed the language some how it got
missed updating on date picker only , so before calling date picker , i just
setting the locale again before initialing datepicker with saved language from shared preferences
lang = Sharedpreferences.getStringValue(context, AppConstants.MS_PREF_SELECTED_LANG_KEY, MSAppConstants.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH_CODE);
LocaleHelper.setLocale(context.getApplicationContext(), lang);